# Settings for pylint in setup.cfg are not getting used

Tags: python, pylint

In order to consolidate the tooling config for python projects, I'm aiming at putting everything in `setup.cfg`. (As that's the only thing supported by `pytype` as well as `flake8` not aiming to support `pyproject.toml` any time soon.)

According to pylint's documentation, this [should be working](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html):

```
setup.cfg in the current working directory, providing it has at least one pylint. section
```

There is neither a `pylintrc` nor a `.pylintrc` in the current directory and `pyproject.toml` doesn't contain any `tool.pylint.` section.

However, the following settings in `setup.cfg` don't get used:

```
[pylint.MASTER]
load-plugins=pylint_django

[pylint.FORMAT]
max-line-length = 123

[pylint.'MESSAGES CONTROL']
disable = missing-docstring,invalid-name
```

This is what `pylint` says:

```
% pylint --generate-rcfile | grep 'max-line-length'
max-line-length=100
```

What might be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

For `MESSAGES CONTROL` you can just use `pylint`:

```
[pylint.MASTER]
load-plugins=pylint_django

[pylint.FORMAT]
max-line-length = 123

[pylint]
disable = missing-docstring,invalid-name
```

Edit: That's potentially because of http://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4272#issuecomment-811898065  that @bers pointed at.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this *is* indeed working. But it helps to avoid conflicting settings further down in `setup.cfg`, like this:

```
[pycodestyle]
max-line-length = 100
```

Here, this setting overrides the `max-line-length` in the `[pylint.FORMAT]` section.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4272#issuecomment-811898065